# US bonds are now paying less vs yields

Tags: meaning

> #### US bonds are now paying less
>
> 3-year US bonds, shorter-term bonds, are now paying less than 5-year ones. For some, that’s a signal of an
> impending recession. Different bonds have different payback dates, and
> yields (the returns on offer) are typically higher for longer-term
> bonds than for shorter-term ones, to compensate for the extra risk
> involved.

I cannot understand that some worry because 3-year US bonds are now paying less, but typically yields are higher for longer-term bonds than for shorter-term ones.

I am confused because I thought that **bond paying** and **yields** have a similar meaning. But it seems they have the opposite meaning, according to the quoted statement.

Please give me a hint.

Comment: The first paragraph states that 3-year bonds are considered to be shorter-term ones. 3-year bonds are paying less than they were, but payments from 5-year bonds are higher than that. No contradiction.

Comment: You may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: I don't understand it either - but that's a question of economics, not English. The contradiction you point out is there, and it's not explained.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Please provide the source**, as context is extremely important to meaning. If your source is this [Finimize article](https://www.finimize.com/wp/news/topsy-turvy/) the text now reads *3-year US bonds are now paying more than 5-year ones*, so whatever you read may have been an editorial error that has now been corrected, or an alteration of the source.

Comment: Rather than [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), I think this question (which is a good one) should be asked on [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/), since it's really about terms like _yield._

Comment: Thank you all!. As #choster said the quotation was came from Finimize article, and it has been corrected. Thank you again!